# angular-formly issue with ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly, angular-ui-select

I am trying to use Angular-Formly together with angular ui-select using $http for results.

The options should refresh as the user types in. When I set the model from another text input, the ui-select updates correctly and show the corresponding results based on what was typed into the text box.

When I however type straight into the ui-select box, I am not getting values back and the templateOptions.options function does not fire and the `$viewvalue` is not updated.

I also don't seem to have access to the `$select.search` results which are updated but are not available in the expressionProperties.

Please see the following JSBin that reproduces the error :

http://jsbin.com/peducofaje/edit

I would appreciate help on this.

Comment: This works for new items, but when you set the model, this does not work as the options are empty.  The refresh does not fire if the model is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an early Christmas present for you. I've updated [the ui-select example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-select) to have exactly what you want :-) A few notes on why yours didn't work:

- expressionProperties only run when the `formState` or `model` changes which is an optimization to reduce the number of watchers (because all expressionProperties share a single watcher). The problem with this is, your model didn't get updated until after an option was selected, so yeah.
- The template was using a `group-By`, but the `templateOptions` didn't have a `groupBy`. You could use a `templateManipulator` to dynamically add a `group-by` if one is present on the `templateOptions`, but my solution doesn't demonstrate this.
- You weren't handling the case where the address search was empty

Also, checkout the note at the top:

```
// NOTE: This next line is highly recommended. Otherwise Chrome's autocomplete will appear over your options!
formlyConfig.extras.removeChromeAutoComplete = true;
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: You could not find better help

Comment: This works great for new records.  However when editing a record...setting the model to existing values, the refresh function does not fire.  Can anyone help to achieve this.